# Messed up checks?

Tags: java, if-statement

Just a brief description of what I am doing - I have random equation generator and buttons with all the digits. In order to answer the question the user has to click the corresponding buttons to form the question(digits are written from left to right) e.g. 9 + 6 = *user clicks 1 and 5*. If the answer is correct another equation should come up. The issue I am encountering for now is that SOMETIMES when the answer is a single digit there is no new equation showing up, nor any errors or something. Just nothing happens. Most of the time this occurs is when the answer is "0". Any idea what might be causing this ? Here is part of the code :

```
public void checkAnswer(){      
    int answer = question.getAnswer();      
        if(ansID2==-1){
            if(String.valueOf(answer).equals(String.valueOf(ansID1))){
                makeEquation();
            }
        }else{
            if(String.valueOf(answer).equals(String.valueOf(ansID1) + String.valueOf(ansID2))){
                makeEquation();
            }
        }
}
```

`ansID2` is set to be `-1` so if the answer is only a single digit the second digit place is skipped. `ansID`'s are assigned when the button with the digit is clicked.

`checkAnswer` is called from a button "Check Answer" with the following code

```
EventHandler checkHandler = new EventHandler(){     
        @Override
        public void handle(Event arg0) {
            checkAnswer();          
        }
    };
```

`ansID2` is set to -1 in the field declaration

Comment: can you show where ansID2 is set to -1?  and from where checkAnswer is called?

Comment: Why are you converting to `String` and performing `String` comparisons when your inputs are fundamentally numeric?

Comment: @JohnBollinger because I have different type of equations - "+", "-", "*" - and I though comparing Strings is going to be faster and with less code(otherwise I have to type in an additional check for the type of equation)

Comment: It is probably some logical error in your part. I think your inner condition for `ansID2==-1` is not met for some reason. Can you either debug or write `else` statement on both inner conditions and see if the flow enters `else` condition?

Comment: @Phantomazi, as far as I can tell, you are comparing a given numeric answer to an expected numeric answer.  The arithmetic operation in the equation yielding the expected answer is irrelevant to that.  Doing it numerically will be faster and more concise, as demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this numerically:

```
public void checkAnswer(){      
    int answer = question.getAnswer();
    int response = ansID1;

    if(ansID2 >= 0) {
        response = 10 * response + ansID2;
    } // else a one-digit response
    if (answer == response) {
        makeEquation();
    }
}
```

At minimum, that's more efficient than performing all the string manipulation you do in the original code.  With that said, I don't see why this version would produce different results from yours.  I'm inclined to suppose that your real problem is elsewhere, such as either the answer or the response digits being incorrect.

In particular, you say

> ansID2 is set to -1 in the field declaration

but that's sufficient only until the first question with a two-digit answer, which will cause `ansID2` to be set to something else.  It (and also `ans1ID`) should be reset when a new equation is created.

Comment: As you said - nothing changed, the exact moment I got an equation with a single digit as an answer the generation of new equations stopped.

Comment: Do consider the comments I added about resetting your variables, especially `ansID2`.

Comment: it was the field declaration. I have missed to reset it after each equation. Thank you !